# Regex: How to extract a particular pattern individually from a text?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract a pattern using regular expression from a text shown bellow.

```
to_timestamp('02-04-09 00:00:00.000000000','RR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'),'REP00061    ',to_timestamp('08-05-30 07:27:36.000000000','RR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'),
```

How can I write a regex in Python to extract following patterns individually?

```
to_timestamp('02-04-09 00:00:00.000000000','RR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
to_timestamp('08-05-30 07:27:36.000000000','RR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

Comment: you mean that each would be on his own line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically using pythex.org you can create your regex with ease.

for example :

```
m = re.findall(r'(to_timestamp\(\'.*?\',\'.*? .*?\'\))',str)
```

the findall in the re module will create a list of all the matches.